# How to create a zip archive containing multiple files and subfolders in memory?

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

The following runs, but leads to a file that unzip fails on:

```
import io
import zipfile

b = io.BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(b, mode='w')
zf.writestr('a/b.txt', 'look here')
zf.writestr('a/c.txt', 'look there')
open('here.zip', 'wb').write(b.getbuffer())
```

Then test:

```
$ unzip here.zip
Archive:  here.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of here.zip or
        here.zip.zip, and cannot find here.zip.ZIP, period.
```

What is missing?

UPDATE:

This seems to work now, not sure if it is maximally compressed or not?

```
import io
import zipfile

b = io.BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(b, mode='w')
zf.writestr('a/b.txt', 'look here')
zf.writestr('a/c.txt', 'look there')
zf.close()
open('here.zip', 'wb').write(b.getbuffer())
```

Comment: What seems to work ? the both codes are same, Also in both the codes, in 6th line single quote is missing before -- look, please fix it

Comment: By default the data won't be compressed maximally (i.e not at all) because you never specify anything else. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) has details on ways to do it. Also note the part about the [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.close) method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code you need to close the zip file after writing data into it. Below is the example code.

```py
import io
import zipfile
b = io.BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(b, mode='w')
zf.writestr('a/b.txt', 'look here')
zf.writestr('a/c.txt', 'look there')
zf.close()
open('here.zip', 'wb').write(b.getbuffer())
```